# Evaluation metrics in network simulator 2 ns2

Tags: ubuntu, simulation, metrics, ns2

I have a wireless network project which is written for detecting Sybil attacks in ns2 and now I'm supposed to evaluate some metrics e.g. Detection rate(DR), False positive rate (FPR), and Average localization error rate (Avg. LEE). Does anybody know how to calculate these evaluation metrics in ns2?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: mostly NS2 is run and installed in Ubuntu